# In AG grid table using dropdown as a cell editor but it is not opening on single Click . For Double Click the dropdown gets open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, ag-grid-react

```
/*DropdownRender */
export default forwardRef(()=>{
    return <span/>
});
```

AG Grid Table with one column as dropdown. React 16 the code was working with single click (Dropdown opens up with single click).

After React upgrade to React 17, double-click is needed to open the dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to set `singleClickEdit=true` in gridOptions.

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-editing-start-stop/#single-click-editing